# Is there a new fix to restart redstone clock

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I think everyone in this section knows about redstone clocks, and that sometimes when you log in and out, the repeaters get stuck. Sometimes they get stuck when you are just a little but far away or in another dimension. This is really annoying if you have stuff that is depending on your clock to work.

Now we are a few updates later, and there have been a lot of updates, and new stuff added to the game. Does anyone know of a new solution to have your clock automatically restarted when it gets stuck.

There are a few methods when I do a YouTube search, but they are all a but messy. Even I did an attempt with a mine cart system, but I think it's messy as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redstone torches don't get stuck like that. Just incorporate at least one torch in your clock and it will be good. However, please note that torches will burn out if they blink too frequently, so you can't have a very fast clock.

Here is a compact design of a clock that uses a torch. It's even toggleable!

[image]

[**This guide**](http://minecraft-guides.net/redstone/clocks.php) discusses some other designs of clocks.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out. Will this produce any additional lag to the system. I guess this is one of those designs where the torch burns out infinitely and creating the burn noise.

Comment: @SaifBechan No.